Firebase Emulator Suite, exporting non default database
DIRECTORY="./STORAGE"
firebase emulators:start --import $DIRECTORY --export-on-exit $DIRECTORY $@

The above works just fine to export the default database, but that's not the one I have in use.  A custom database is being used instead for development and I'd like to persist all that storage to resume where I last left off.
Would this be automated behaviour where ALL information gets exported? If so, how come the custom database always comes back as empty?  Should I do export only instead of on-exit maybe the shutdown is somehow interrupting the save?
Or is non default database simply not supported for exit?

As per the documentation, currently Firestore emulator doesn’t support non-default databases.

Currently, the Emulator Suite UI supports interactive creation, editing, deletion, request monitoring, and security visualization for a default database, but not additional named databases.

I suggest you raise a feature request on Firebase forum if this is affecting your approach.
